# Is there a way to view an HP ProLiant server IML log from within ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, logging, hp, hp-proliant

I'm investigating a system outage on an [HP ProLiant DL360 G7](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13598_na/13598_na.html) server running VMware ESXi 5.1.

While I'm a huge advocate of installing the HP-specific management agents for ESXi or using the customized .ISO image, I never noticed that a few command-line utilities I use on other platforms are missing:

```
#  esxcli software vib list| grep -i hewlett
char-hpcru                     5.0.3.09-1OEM.500.0.0.434156        Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24  
char-hpilo                     500.9.0.0.9-1OEM.500.0.0.434156     Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24  
hp-ams                         500.9.2.0-11.434156                 Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24  
hp-smx-provider                500.03.01.10.2-434156               Hewlett-Packard  VMwareAccepted    2013-01-24  
hpacucli                       9.20-9.0                            Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24  
hpbootcfg                      01-01.02                            Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24  
hponcfg                        04-00.10                            Hewlett-Packard  PartnerSupported  2013-01-24
```

On Windows and Linux HP ProLiant systems, I make use of the `hpasmcli` or `hplog` command-line tools to replay/examine the system's Integrated Management Log (IML). It's essentially the server's event log. This is also available in the ILO interface.

As it happens, the system I'm working on doesn't seem to have its ILO connected and configured. It's unreachable... *(I know, fix the ILO...)*

**Is there a quick way to examine the system's event log from the ESXi host side?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tools are not included in the HP Offline Bundles, so you won't be able to do this out-of-the-box.
However, you may be able to run the Linux binaries of hpasmcli and hplog in ESXi. I know that this was possible with hpacucli (before HP made it officially available for ESXi). See this post: http://www.v-front.de/2012/03/how-to-run-hp-online-acu-cli-for-linux.html

Comment: I've tried this approach when I was in a bind, too... You are correct in that the native HP drivers don't offer insight into the IML log. It *can* be read from the `Hardware Status` tab in the vSphere client, though - Under the `System Event Log` -> `IPMI SEL` menu. I ended up getting the ILO configured properly in this case. Thanks for the answer, though.