# HP Proliant ML310 G4 power supply warning

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

One of the two power supplies in my HP Proliant ML310 G4 server has an amber/orange LED lit in one of the power supplies on the front panel. Also, the wave symbol is flashing in orange/amber. When looking on the backside of the server only one of the power supplies has a green light, the other one is not lit at all.

I have tried to replace the power supply (without the green light) with another one that is working but nothing happened.
Does this mean that something is wrong inside the server? Maybe with the backplane? Or can it be something else?

Is it OK to keep the server running with just one functional power supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you replaced the bad power supply with a *known-good* power supply, you should have had a green light on the new power supply. Have you verified that utility and UPS power are okay?

You can check your operating system's logs to understand what the server thinks is wrong. Specifically, the HP IML log will tell you what's up. You can also get this information if you reboot and watch the [POST messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

Which operating system are you using?

Comment: We are running VMWare ESXi (4.1). On it we are running 4 Windows servers. Is it possible to install "HP ProLiant Remote Monitor Service" on a guest OS and access the HP IML log?

Comment: Oddly enough, the IML log is only available via the ILO when used with a VMware ESXi system. If you have the agents installed, you can also view some of this in the SEL log within ESXi's hardware tab. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/510967/is-there-a-way-to-view-an-hp-proliant-server-iml-log-from-within-esxi

Comment: Thank you @ewwhite. And for a dummy like me, here is a guide on how to access the ILO: http://808techblog.com/?p=32

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that something is wrong inside the server? Maybe with
>   the backplane?

Yes it does, that's exactly what it means - you can keep it running on one PSU - only you know if you're happy with the risk.